# Xamarin - Button with text and image in absolute layout results in mis-aligned elements

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, custom-controls, custom-renderer

I am trying to create a button in a Xamarin Forms cross-platform app (iOS and Android), where the button has both text and an image.  The XAML is pretty straightforward:

```
<AbsoluteLayout ...>
   <Labels and backgrounds and such>
   <Button x:Name="HomeButton2" TranslationX="6" TranslationY="100"
     BackgroundColor="#efeff4" TextColor="#4a4a4a"
     WidthRequest="58" HeightRequest="76"
     ContentLayout="Top,5" 
     Image="TaskBar_Assets_HomeButtonIcon.png" Text="Home"
     Clicked="HomeButton_Clicked" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

but what I get on the iPad is a button where both the image and the text are strangely pushed over to the side:

[image: home button offset]

(the source image "TaskBar_Assets_HomeButtonIcon.png" is 47 x 44 so it should fit fine in the overall button area)

The only way I can find to make this look better, is to make a custom control based on Button, and then I can see that several of the properties of the underlying UIButton seem wonky:

The Control.ImageView.Frame is all zeroes:

```
Control.ImageView = <UIImageView: 0x12df52940; frame = (0 0; 0 0);
   clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO;
   layer = <CALayer: 0x173623180>>
```

The Control.ImageEdgeInsets and .TitleEdgeInsets look odd (the right + left seem like they leave no space for the image or text):

```
Control.ImageEdgeInsets = {-8.9501953125, 20.33935546875, 8.9501953125, -20.33935546875}
Control.TitleEdgeInsets = {22, -23.5, -22, 23.5}
```

What I'm doing, is adjusting the Control.ImageEdgeInsets so that Control.ImageEdgeInsets.Left is equal to the half of the (button width minus the image width) and setting Control.ImageEdgeInsets.Right to zero (for no particular reason except that it works)

and then figuring out what to set Control.TitleEdgeInsets was done with trial & error, I ended up with values related to the width of the "Home" text (41 pixels):

```
Control.ImageEdgeInsets updated to {-8.9501953125, 5.5, 8.9501953125, 0}
Control.TitleEdgeInsets updated to {22, -50, -22, -9}
```

That results in a reasonable button look:

[image]

although it looks like I need to do more trial & error to get the text "Home" actually centered.

But why do I need to go through all this?  Why doesn't the button just display text & image correctly in the first place?

And if I do have to go through all this, why are the values for Left & Right for ImageEdgeInsets and TitleEdgeInsets so different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the articles I have read about images on buttons suggest constructing your own using an Image and a Label in a grid using a gesture recognizer to handle the tap.

You could also try a button and an image in a grid.

Use Margin to adjust placement.

I try and stay clear of absolute layout.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ButtonRenderer source code from [Xamarin.Froms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/e8660383b03b4010724b36c6eef471a2e74e7c98/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs#L273).If you set the ContentLayout to `Top`, the below codes will be run:

```
void ComputeEdgeInsets(UIButton button, Button.ButtonContentLayout layout)
{
    ...
    var horizontalImageOffset = labelWidth / 2;
    var horizontalTitleOffset = imageWidth / 2;

    ...
    button.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(-imageVertOffset, horizontalImageOffset, imageVertOffset, -horizontalImageOffset);
    button.TitleEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(titleVertOffset, -horizontalTitleOffset, -titleVertOffset, horizontalTitleOffset);
}
```

As the codes show, the Left offset of **image** is `horizontalImageOffset` which is `labelWidth / 2`. The Left offset of **title** is `horizontalTitleOffset` which is `imageWidth / 2`.

So, when the text is wider, the left offset of image will be bigger. When the image is wider, the left offset of text will be bigger.

**Edit**:

In native iOS, the default layout is like the left image: Image is at left and Label is at right. In Xamarin for `Top` setting, Xamarin moves the Image up and right, moves the Label down and left to makes them like the right image. I paint this illustration, hope it clear.

[image]

Comment: Interesting ... so I guess my first question is this: do you know what these inset values are supposed to represent?  I can't imagine what the edge insets are such that the image insets depend on the text ,and the text insets depend on the image ...

Comment: And then ... it doesn't work.  Those values are, in fact, what the code is giving me (early on in this post, values I said "looked odd") and it's not right.