# Xamarin forms button with both text and vector image on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms PCL project, I'm trying to create a button with a text shown below an image. But as soon as I add the image (which is a Vector image - and no way of specifying size?) - the text disappears. Only the image is displayed.

Any ideas on why the text is disappearing when the image is shown?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Button xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyProj.Views.ToolbarButtonView"
        Text="hello" 
        Image="myvectorimage" 
        ContentLayout="Top,1" >
</Button>
```

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Add a Image with the form that you wanna watch the button and your actual  button. For more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here(Kevin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779907/xamarin-button-with-text-and-image-in-absolute-layout-results-in-mis-aligned-e/46805191#46805191) is a better answer to explain the image and text on Button.

I think it is better to use a `StackLayout`(adding TapGesture) with Image and Label instead of Button. It is more controllable.